# Android smooth ListView scrolling while loading contact photos

Tags: android, list, listview, bitmap, android-contacts

I am using this method to load contacts photo, in my extended CursorAdapter (With LoaderManager):

```
private Bitmap loadContactPhoto(Uri contactUri) {
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        InputStream stream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    }
```

My contacts ListView using QuickContactBadge at each item, and the ListView does not scroll smooth, even if the contacts have no images.

Can I load the images in AsyncTask or make the loading faster?

Answer (score 0):

Use this generally used method to heavily optimize your listviews via recycling:
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKGoKnhN_Ys)

You should tailor the above method to work with the general method, ie only use the code you gave only so many times.

However, if you've already tailored the general optimization method to your needs as is and it's still quite slow, you SHOULD use an AsyncTask. The following link should get you set up- just use a placeholder image until the task is done, then save the image with the view object so you don't have to get the image again when the user re-scrolls through.
[Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Comment: Here's a blog with the recycling method [couldn't attach earlier]: http://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

Comment: You know how to use an AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes. Do you need help using it?

Comment: Yes. Can you help me build AsyncTask?

Comment: Use that very last link I posted, and update with what you've tried so far, including the code for the listview as well as the AsyncTask parts, and anything else you believe is related. [Although I seriously consider that to be an another entire question, to be honest. Maybe open another, more specific question what you've tried and mark this answered?]